# awk num function error

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I am trying to execute 3 command and get the output as a variable which needs some percentage calculation and display the same as the example. can this be executed as script.

I cant save the data on the host where i execute the command, My script will be on local system which will get executed on the remote host and brig the data back to my local machine. is there any possible approach for achieving this task.

First command output

```
$ isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail"
Size:573T
Used:448.0T
Avail:74T
```

Second command output

```
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "\t\t\tSnapshot USED %=%.1f%%\n", $4}'
     Snapshot USED =0.6%
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n -1 | awk '{ print "\t\t\tSnapshot USED:" $1}'
     Snapshot USED=3.2T
```

example script awk script not working. after removed space

```
# isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail" | awk 'function print (num)
pipe pipe quote> /Size:/ {TotalSize=$NF~}
pipe pipe quote> /Used:/ {TotalUsed=$NF}
pipe pipe quote> /Avail:/ {TotalAvail=$NF} }
pipe pipe quote> END {
pipe pipe quote>     used=TotalUsed/Total_Size*100
pipe pipe quote>     system("isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n -1 | awk '{ print "Snapshot_used=" $1}'")
pipe pipe quote>     system("isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "Snapshot_per :%.1f\n", $4}'")
pipe pipe quote>     Usedw/o=Total Used-Snapshot USED/Total Size
pipe pipe quote>     print hostname ": " "\t","Total Size:" Total_Size
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tTotalUsed:%.1f\n", TotalUsed, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tTotalAvail:%.1f\n", TotalAvail, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tTotalUsed %:%.1f\n", used, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tSnapshot Used :%.1f\n", Snapshot_used, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tSnapshot Used %:%.1f\n", Snapshot_per, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tUsed w/o:%.1f\n", Usedw/o, TB)'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        function >>>  print <<<  (num)
        missing }
        missing )
awk: bailing out at source line 7
```

Sample Requirement

```
Total Size      : 573 TB
Total Used      : 448.0 TB
Total Available : 74 TB
Total Used %    : 86.1 %   # Total Used(%) = Total Used/Total Size *100 = 86.1(%)
Snapshot Used   : 3.2 TB
Snapshot Used % : 0.6 %
Used w/o        : 85.5 %    # {(Total used)-(Snapshot used)} / (Total size) = 85.49%
```

Comment: If your question is about awk, get rid of all the extraneous stuff. Save the results of `isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail"` in a file.  Make that file as small as possible (one line?) where it still demonstrates the problem with your awk command. Make the awk script as small as possible where it still gives the error. There's a good chance by then you'll see the problem but if not post the small input, the small script, the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: I will be running this on multiple host and noway we can store the output in a file (not allowed). On my local system this script will be present and i will push this script to be executed on the host and bring the result back to a file.

Comment: @jas isn't telling you that's the solution, she's telling you that's how to create a [mcve] to ask your question. You're asking for help parsing the output of `isi_whatever` - we dont have that command so how do we know what it's output/the input to awk looks like if you don't show us? What is "Sample Requirement" - the sample input or the expected output? Whichever it is the other one is missing. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some syntax issues with your awk code.  Here's a start if you insist on using shell + awk

Use ':' as the IFS  ('-F:')

store input from stdin (trailing '-') in an array indexed by key label e.g. Size

$NF+0 to have awk get rid of pesky trailing 'T'  **be aware if the units change (i.e. to G) you'll need that info to normalize

```
    [stdin] | awk -F\: '{a[$1]=($NF+0)} END{ ... grind stats here ...}' -
```